# How to make eclipse stop complaining about valid syntax

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am using eclipse with python bindings and there is a line that is showing as an error, even though it compiles and runs. I am guessing it has something to do with Python 2 vs. 3. The line in question is:

```
exec_dict = { **{"objectclass": objectclass}, **{"network_id": network_id}, **conditions }
```

I tried going into

**Project > Options > PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar**

and changing the Grammer Version to 3.0-3.5 and the interpreter to python_35, but it is still showing up as invalid syntax.

Comment: Do bad things happen if you comment this line out?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried running that on Python and got:

```
python
Python 3.6.4 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Dec 24 2017, 10:11:43) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exec_dict = { **{"objectclass"}: objectclass, **{"network_id": network_id}, **conditions }
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    exec_dict = { **{"objectclass"}: objectclass, **{"network_id": network_id}, **conditions }
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, it seems that the syntax is really invalid...

Comment: There was indeed a syntax error in the original question post - I had to type it manually while looking at another screen, because I am coding on a remote desktop that is very finnicky with copy/pasting between them. I edited the original post. But then anyway it seems as though after going home for the day and coming back it no longer complains, so I guess just a restart was required.